# Spotify Flash Integration

Tags: javascript, flash, iframe, spotify, spotify-app

I'm trying to build a Spotify app that displays a Youtube video in an iFrame. I've done this and it works in a normal browser. However, when I attempt to run it in Spotify, I get an error in the iFrame saying `The Adobe Flash Player or an HTML5 supported browser is required for video playback.` I've installed Flash manually, outside of Google Chrome, so I know that it's there. I was wondering if there was anything else I needed to do in order to enable Flash in a Spotify app. Perhaps something in the `manifest.json`?

Here is my source for my `player`, which is almost straight from the Youtube demo:

```
  var tag = document.createElement('script');

  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'Gz2GVlQkn4Q',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash is not supported in the built-in browser used by Spotify Apps on the Spotify Desktop Client. You can find a information about the supported capabilities in the [Spotify Developer Guidelines](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/guidelines/developer/#browser-capabilities).

Comment: And that explains the HTML5 fallback error, too, I guess.  The <video> element is not supported until Chrome 31 and that page says Spotify's embedded Chrome is equivalent to Chrome 29.